# Complex Integration of $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

Out of Stein's book, we're asked to show find a formula for $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)\,dx,\quad a>0.$$While this is very doable via integration by parts, I'm asked to use contour integration, where we're suggested to integrate over a sector with angle $\omega$ such that $\cos(\omega)=a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$

I've attempted this multiple times, and I keep having trouble with some integrals. I've set the contour up so that on the first segment, it's on the real axis, so we have the integral $$\int_0^R e^{-az}\cos(bz)\,dz.$$ Then I parameterize the arc as $z(\theta)=Re^{i\theta}$ for $0\leq\theta\leq \omega$, so the second integral becomes $$\int_0^\omega e^{-a(Re^{i\theta})}\cos(b(Re^{i\theta}))\left(iRe^{i\theta}\right)\,d\theta.$$The final segment I parameterized as $z(t)=Re^{i\omega}(1-t)$ and set up the final integral as $$\int_0^1e^{-a(Re^{i\omega}(1-t))}\cos\big(b(Re^{i\omega}(1-t))\big)(-Re^{i\omega})\,dt.$$I've tried finding some way to bound one of the last two integrals so that I can show one of them goes to $0$ as $R\to\infty$, but I've not had any luck. Will someone make a suggestion if my approach and parameterizations are correct? Thanks!

**Update**: My thoughts are really that the integral which goes to zero is the arc. I keep working it down in the following way; we know that it is 
\begin{align}
&\leq R\int_0^\omega\left|e^{-aR(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}\cdot\left(\frac{e^{ibRe^{i\theta}}+e^{-ibRe^{i\theta}}}{2}\right)\right|\,d\theta\\
&\leq\frac{R}{2}\int_0^\omega\left|e^{-aR\cos\theta}\cdot\left(e^{ibR(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}+e^{-bR(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}\right)\right|\,d\theta\\
&\leq\frac{R}{2}\int_0^\omega\left|e^{-aR\cos\theta-bR\sin\theta}\right|+\left|e^{-aR\cos\theta+bR\sin\theta}\right|\,d\theta.
\end{align}
At this point, it is easy to show that the first term tends to zero, since $(-aR\cos\theta)<0$ and $bR\sin\theta>0$ (since $b$ and $\sin\theta$ have the same sign). The second term, however is what causes me trouble. I just finished working it out again, and I get that it *only* goes to zero if $a^2>b^2$, which isn't necessary in the general formula when achieved by integration by parts. I am really at a loss...

**Added Solution**: See the solution I've posted and please leave comments on your thoughts about it. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the exercise? http://books.google.com/books/princeton?id=0ECHh9tjPUAC&pg=PA64&img=1&pgis=1&dq=cos(bx)&sig=ACfU3U0rcM7d62kEoDlsLgzywazWfac4zg&edge=0

Comment: +1 I have never seen like this one just in Riemannian  integral for reals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as $a>0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-(a-ib)x}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-(a^2+b^2)x}\mathrm{d}(a+ib)x\right)\tag{$\ast$}\\
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{a+ib}{a^2+b^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a^2+b^2)x}\mathrm{d}(a^2+b^2)x\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{a+ib}{a^2+b^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}
\end{align}
$$
Step $(\ast)$ is simply adding
$$
\mathrm{Re}\left(\int_\gamma e^{-(a-ib)z}\,\mathrm{d}z\right)
$$
where $\gamma$ is the contour that goes from $0$ to $|z|=R$ along the curve $(a+ib)x$ ($x$ from $0$ to $\infty$), then follows $|z|=R$ to the positive real axis, and then back along the real axis to $0$. There are no singularities inside $\gamma$ so the integral is $0$. The integral along the arc of $|z|=R$ vanishes as $R\to\infty$.

---

**Why the integral along the curve vanishes**

Without loss of generality, assume $b>0$. Parameterizing $\gamma(t)=R(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))$ and setting $\tan(\theta)=b/a$
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\int_0^\theta e^{-(a-ib)R(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))}\,\mathrm{d}R(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,R\int_0^\theta e^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R(\cos(t-\theta)+i\sin(t-\theta))}\,i(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))\,\mathrm{d}t\,\right|\\
&\le R\int_0^\theta e^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R\cos(t-\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=R\int_0^\theta e^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R\cos(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\le R\int_0^\theta e^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R(1-2t/\pi)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=Re^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R}\int_0^\theta e^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R(2t/\pi)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} Re^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R}\left(e^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R(2\theta/\pi)}-1\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} R\left(e^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R(2\theta/\pi-1)}-e^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}R}\right)\tag{$\lozenge$}
\end{align}
$$
Since $0\le\theta\lt\pi/2$, the coefficient of $R$ in each exponential is negative. Thus, $(\lozenge)$ tends to $0$ as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: I think that last statement is what the OP wanted to prove.  I made an attempt in my answer.  I really like how the integrals only converge over the arc and nowhere else.

Comment: @rlgordonma: I have given a detailed proof of the vanishing of the integral along $|z|=R$. I hope it is not too obscure.

Comment: I get it.  It feels less "natural" than mine, but from my quick read, I see that it works because $\cos{t} \ge 1 - (2/\pi) t$ over $t \in (0,\pi/2)$. Bravo. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn: This seems like a slick proof, but the ($*$) and immediately thereafter loses me just a little bit. Want to elaborate that point a little bit? By the way, the explanation why the integral vanished on the arc is superb. +1$

Answer (score 9):

We have
    \begin{align*}
  &\int_0^Re^{-Az}\,dz+\int_0^{\omega}e^{-A(Re^{i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}\,d\theta+\int_0^Re^{-A(R-t)e^{i\omega}}(-e^{i\omega})\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{A}+\underbrace{\int_0^{\omega}e^{-A(Re^{i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}\,d\theta}_{\text{vanishes as $R\longrightarrow\infty$}}-\int_0^Re^{-At(\cos\omega+i\sin\omega)}(e^{i\omega})\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{A}-\int_0^Re^{-at-ibt}\left(\frac{a}{A}+i\frac{b}{A}\right)\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{A}-\frac{a}{A}\int_0^Re^{-at-ibt}\,dt-i\frac{b}{A}\int_0^Re^{-at-ibt}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{A}-\frac{a}{A}\int_0^Re^{-at}\big(\cos(bt)-i\sin(bt)\big)\,dt-i\frac{b}{A}\int_0^Re^{-at}\big(\cos(bt)-i\sin(bt)\big)\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{A}-\frac{a}{A}\int_0^Re^{-at}\cos(bt)\,dt-\frac{b}{A}\int_0^Re^{-at}\sin(bt)\,dt\\
&\hspace{0.5in}+i\left(\frac{a}{A}\int_0^Re^{-at}\sin(bt)\,dt-\frac{b}{A}\int_0^{R}e^{-at}\cos(bt)\,dt\right).
 \end{align*}

**Argument for Vanishing** Here the integral over the arc vanishes since
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\int_0^{\omega}e^{-A(Re^{i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}\,d\theta\right|&\leq R\int_0^\omega\left|e^{-AR\cos\theta}\right|\,d\theta\\&\leq R\int_0^\omega e^{-AR(1-2\theta/\pi)}\,d\theta
\end{align*}$$and now it is easy to show that the integral goes to $0$.

**Finsihed Solution** Now we can set this up as a linear system since we know the real part and imaginary parts must be zero; so we have the equations
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{A}-\frac{a}{A}U-\frac{b}{A}V=0\\
&\hspace{0.15in}-\frac{b}{A}U+\frac{a}{A}V=0.
\end{align*}
Solving the system yields
$$
U=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}
$$
and
$$
V=\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}
$$
as desired, where $U=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)\,dx$ and $V=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sin(bx)\,dx$.

Comment: I really like this answer, but I am wondering what happened to the R term on the third integral in the first equation:

It goes $$\int_0^Re^{-A(R-t)e^{iw}}(-e^{iw})=-\int_0^Re^{-Ate^{iw}}(e^{iw})$$

Can you elaborate on what happened here? Thanks.

Comment: @Craig: Just use substitution with $u=R-t$.

Comment: I see, in which case the upper bound of the integral would be $u+t$, and safely you might as well call this $R$ because it's tending to infinity all the same?

Comment: @Craig: Not quite. The upper bound of the integral would be $0$, the lower bound is $R$, and we get a negative factor from the fact that $du=-dt$. This allows you to switch the bounds of the integral without problem.

Comment: I have two questions @Clayton. The first integral on the contour should be $\int_{0}^{R} e^{-Ax} dx$ since we are traversing only on the x-axis. Also, in the third integral why do you have $R-t$ ? I took it as $\int_{0}^{R} e^{-Ate^{iw} }e^{iw} dt$ since it is over the line with angle $iw$ going from 0 to R.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is OK, at least technically correct, but why keep the integration limits of the wedge boundary at $(0,1)$, when you want them to be $(0,\infty)$? Viz,

$$\oint_C dz \: e^{-a z} e^{i b z} = 0$$

by Cauchy's Theorem.  So, yes $C$ has 3 pieces, one being the pos. real line, one an arc, and the other the line $z=e^{i \omega}t$:

$$ e^{i \omega} \int_{-\infty}^0 dt \: \exp{[-(a-i b) (\cos{\omega} + i \sin{\omega}) t]} + \int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{-a x} e^{i b x} + \int_{C_R} dz \: e^{-a z} e^{i b z} = 0  $$

where $C_R$ is the arc of the wedge.  I will show below that the integral over $C_R$ vanishes.  That leaves the other two integrals, which ad to zero.  Rearranging the sum, we get

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{-a x} e^{i b x} = e^{i \omega} \int_0^{\infty} dt \: e^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2} t}$$

Taking the real part of both sides:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{-a x} \cos{(b x)} = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$

Going back to the integral over the arc, we find it takes the form, depending on the sign of $b$,

$$\int_{C_R} dz \: e^{-a z} e^{\pm i b z} = i R \int_0^{\omega} d \theta \: e^{i \theta}  \exp{[-a R (\cos{\theta} + i \sin{\theta})]} \exp{[\pm i b R (\cos{\theta} + i \sin{\theta})]}  $$

which is bounded by

$$R \int_0^{\omega} d \theta \: \exp{[-R (a \cos{\theta} - b \sin{\theta})]}  $$

Note that the argument of the exponent is positive only within the integration range, which works out perfectly.  Therefore, on the arc of the wedge, the integral vanishes in the limit as $R \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: It is probably not too difficult, but you should probably show that $a\cos(\theta)-b\sin(\theta)\ge c\gt0$ so that the coefficient of $R$ is $\le-c$.

Comment: @robjohn and rlgordonma: I don't see why it should be the case that $a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta>0$ at all, since this is equivalently $a\cos\theta>b\sin\theta$, thus $1>(b/a)\tan\theta$. The maximum tangent is in this range is $b/a$, thus we end up with $a^2>b^2$, which is what I got at the end... Help?

Comment: @Clayton: between $0$ and $\omega$, $a \cos{\theta} - b \sin{theta}$ goes between $a$ and $0$.

Comment: @Clayton Could this be fixed by switching the roles of $a$ and $b$ in the definition of $\omega$?

Comment: @rlgordonma: I still don't see why: obviously at $\theta=0$, we have equality with $a$, but at $\omega$, I see that we have $$\frac{a^2-b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Comment: @ErickWong: Not as far as I can tell; then we'd just have to have $b^2>a^2$ I think.

Comment: @Clayton We would have $\tan \theta \le a/b$ rather than  $b/a$, hence $a \cos \theta \ge b \sin \theta$.

Comment: @Clayton: I think it should be $a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta)$ since $$\mathrm{Re}\Big((a-ib)(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))\Big) =a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta) =\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(\omega-\theta)$$ where $\tan(\omega)=b/a$ and $0\le\theta\le\omega$. Then $\cos(\omega)\le\cos(\omega-\theta)\le1$.

Comment: @robjohn: I see. So instead of killing the $e^{ibR(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}$, you're suggesting to keep it and consider the real part, which happens to take this nice form which can easily be seen to be positive. Is this the right idea?

Comment: @Clayton: yes. That is the idea. The exponent is supposed to be largely negative.  If it gets near $0$, things get big and the largeness of the arc keeps the integral from vanishing.

Comment: @Clayton: I think you caught something.  For negative $b$, I think you need to use a contour in the lower half plane.  In that case, you still get the full, unquestioned positive in the exponent.

Comment: @rlgordonma: I don't think the sign of $b$ matters; since $b\sin\theta$ will be positive anyway. That is, if $b<0$, then $\sin\theta<0$, so $b\sin\theta>0$, so I think we'd still have the same problem.

Comment: @Clayton: If $b\ge0$ the integrand is $e^{-(a-ib)z}$, then the contour needs to be in the first quadrant. However, the problem can also be done using $e^{-(a+ib)z}$, and then the contour needs to be in the fourth quadrant. If $b\le0$, switch the quadrants.

Comment: @robjohn: Maybe I'm just missing something, but what does that say? I understand there are different quadrants depending on the sign of $b$, but by your second statement, it seems to me that we could just skip part of the first statement and suppose the integrand is $e^{-(a-ib)z}$, since if $b>0$, this is what we want, and otherwise, $e^{-(a-i(-b))}$ works.

Comment: @robjohn: Basically, since cosine is even, whether $b>0$ or $b<0$, since if $b<0$, we can just take $-b$, and nothing in the integrand changes. Therefore, WLOG, we can take $b>0$ and avoid any nuisances arising from $b<0$, right?

Comment: @Clayton: you seem to be thinking about the fact that in the posed problem, the sign of $b$ does not matter since $\cos(bx)=\cos(-bx)$. However, in carrying out the contour integration, we need to make sure that the integral along the arc of the wedge vanishes, and for this to occur, we need to match the sign of $b$ and the particular character, $e^{-(a+ib)x}$ or $e^{-(a-ib)x}$, we are using with the contour we are using.

Comment: @robjohn: But in any case, if $b<0$, can we not substitute $c=-b$ and then we have $$\int e^{-ax}\cos(cx)\,dx$$with $c>0$? Then the integrals are identical, and the coefficient of $x$ inside of cosine is positive. So I'm just not seeing why the sign of $b$ makes a difference...

Comment: @Clayton: You confirm the supposition in the first sentence of my last comment. In the real, $\mathbb{R}$, problem, the sign of $b$ makes no difference since $\cos(x)$ is even. However, in $\mathbb{C}$, we can demonstrate the same problem using the character $e^{-(1+2i)z}$$. We want to use the contour $z=(1-2i)t$ and $R(\cos(t)-i\sin(t))$ for $0\le t\le\tan^{-1}(2)$. If we were to use $z=(1+2i)t$ and $R(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))$, the integrand on the arc does not decay as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: @robjohn: Thank you. I think I understand now; you've been very patient with me. If you've been frustrated with my ignorance, your writing hasn't betrayed you and now I have a better understanding than what I had before, so thank you for that.