# Complex Integration doubt in the solution

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to find the value of $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)\,dx,\quad a>0.$$

by integrating $e^{−Az} ,A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, over an appropriate sector with angle $ω$, with $cos ω=\dfrac{a}{A}$.

I'm seeing some solutions and I have the following questions:

1) It seems $ω= cos^{−1}(a/A)$ is strictly between 0 and $\pi/2$?

2) Why is it true that $\cos(\theta) \geq 1 - \dfrac{2\theta}{\pi} $? 
how to prove?

Can someone answer both questions with details?

Comment: you are trying to solve the integral?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/300384/8581) is a nice approach done by great @robjohn.

Comment: Yes, I tried to solve it, but I did not understand these two details

Comment: To me, it is just the Laplace of $\cos(bx)$.

Comment: As @mrs said using Laplace transform 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)\,dx=\dfrac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Not sure what you're asking, but you can find an antiderivative of the integrand by considering
$$\int e^{ax}\cos bx\;dx + i\int e^{ax}\sin bx\;dx\tag{1}$$
$$\int e^{ax}(\cos bx + i\sin bx)\;dx =\int e^{(a+bi)x}\; dx$$
$$= \frac{e^{(a+bi)x}}{a+bi} + C$$
$$=\frac{e^{ax}e^{ibx}(a-bi)}{(a+bi)(a-bi)} + C$$
$$=\frac{e^{ax}(\cos bx + i \sin bx)(a-bi)}{a^2+b^2} + C$$
$$=\left[\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\cos bx + b\sin bx\right)+C_1\right] + i\left[\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\sin bx - b\cos bx\right)+C_2\right]\tag{2}$$
Then equate real parts of (1) and (2) to get what you need to proceed with the definite integration. Is that helpful?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. To me, this is a really neat trick that reduces a complicated-looking integral to a very elementary one. Now this will be in your toolbox forever! ;)